# SSH host key changes when SOCKS proxy created with 'ssh -D'

Tags: proxy, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a remote machine which I sometimes use as a SOCKS proxy, using the command:

```
ssh -D 9999 REMOTEMACHINE
```

SSH works fine when the proxy connection does not exist, but if the proxy connection exists and I try to start a second connection, I get the following error:

```
The RSA host key for REMOTEMACHINE has changed
```

If I then close the proxy connection, SSH works fine again, without having to update the key.

Why does the 'ssh -D' command appear to alter the host key and how can I stop that from happening?